# Fire button click via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I need to 'click' one button using JavaScript, when the user clicks another button.**

In Chrome on Mac, the following works fine. However, in Safari on Mac, clicking the button simply reloads the current page, rather than triggering the expected behaviour.

JS

```
$( 'document' ).ready( function() {
    var $myForm = $('#my-form');
    $('#button-fake').on('click', function(){
        console.log("FAKE CLICKED");
        if ($myForm[0].checkValidity()){
            console.log("FORM VALID");
            $('#button-real').click();
            console.log("FORM SUBMITTED");
        }
    });              
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="button-fake" value="Fake button" />

<input type="submit" id="button-real" value="Real button" />
```

PS: Not my idea, I just need to get it working.

Comment: Why can't you extrapolate the code to a common function and call that?

Comment: Whatever button-real runs is a blackbox.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add `e.preventDefault();`

```js
var $myForm = $('#my-form');
$('#button-fake').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("FAKE CLICKED");
  if ($myForm[0].checkValidity()) {
    console.log("FORM VALID");
    $('#button-real').click();
    console.log("FORM SUBMITTED");
  }
});

$('#button-real').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('button-real clicked')

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='my-form'>
  <input type='text' required>
  <button type='submit' id='button-fake'>Submit</button>
  <button type='button' id='button-real'>Real</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Just realised: If I add e.preventDefault(), it no longer triggers the HTML 5 form validation messages. So that's not an option

Answer (score 1):

The button will trigger a form submit. The form submit will reload the page. To prevent this, call preventDefault().

```
$( 'document' ).ready( function() {
        var $myForm = $('#my-form');
        $('#button-fake').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); // <- This
                console.log("FAKE CLICKED");
                if ($myForm[0].checkValidity()){
                        console.log("FORM VALID");
                        $('#button-real').click();
                        console.log("FORM SUBMITTED");
                }
        });              
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed that! PS: Same answer as @brk, but more explanatory detail, therefore I am accepting this solution.

Comment: Just realised: If I add `e.preventDefault()`, it no longer triggers the HTML 5 form validation messages. So that's not an option.

Comment: I don't feel there is a way to actually circumvent that... You could try replace the HTML5 validation with a javascript based one